# Getting all elements starting with a specific character in a linked list

Tags: java

I have a linked list that I created on my own. I want to retrieve **all the elements** that start with the last character of a given input in the following method.

```
public String tracker(String w)
{
    SampleNode d = head();

    while(d != null)
    {
        if(w.charAt(w.length() -1) == d.getElement().charAt(0))
        {
            return d.getElement();
        }
        d = d.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code that I have above only returns the first element only but I want all the elements. How do I do so? Thanks!

edit: For anybody who needs the correct answer

```
public List tracker(String w)
{
    SampleNode d = head();
    LinkedList another = new LinkedList();

    while(d != null)
    {
        if(w.charAt(w.length() -1) == d.getElement().charAt(0))
        {
            another.add(d.getElement());
        }
        d = d.getNext();
    }
    return another;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wont give you the working code but can tell you how to do.

You are just returning the element right away inside the loop. That is what you want however.

Take list, keep adding then and in the end, return the list.

You are almost done, just take a new list, add to the list inside if condition and return in the end.

Comment: So the method should now return a new list then, instead of a string?

Comment: I've added the new code according to your instruction in the OP. It does the job! Thank you!

Comment: One extra query... is there a way to return a `null` or something to that effect if the if condition fails?

Comment: You can use `return another.isEmpty() ? null : another;`

Comment: just before returning the linked list you filled with results, check for the size of it. If the size is zero, you know what to return ;)

Comment: I'm assuming that there will definitely be cases where the IF condition will hold true. Therefore, `another` can never be empty. With that in mind, what should I do for the cases when the IF condition fails?

Answer (score 3):

If you want all elements including duplicate entries then you should better use List, as in example below:

```
public List<String> tracker(String w) {
    SampleNode d = head();
    // declare list to populate with all elements
    List<String> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
    while (d != null) {
        if (w.charAt(w.length() - 1) == d.getElement().charAt(0)) {
             // add element to the list
             allElements.add(d.getElement());
        }
        d = d.getNext();
    }

    return allElements;
}
```

Comment: I can't use List for this task. Only the linked list I've build can be used unfortunately.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Scary. In a good and kind world, every `LinkedLiist` is `List`.